# Change link of "recent reviews"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, hyperlinks

From the front page one can select review to go to the categories of review tasks. For each category one can on the right select "recent reviews". Clicking this link takes one to the statistics page instead of the list of recently reviewed posts.

I suggest changing the link so that it directs to the list of recently reviewed posts.

Comment: I kinda like the info you currently get. What about adding this functionality with a 2nd button or so (as I can also see how what you suggest is useful)?

Comment: @gnometorule: I would be fine with a second button. I would also be fine with just changing the text on the link from "recent reviews" to something that better represents where the links go. The recent reviews makes me think of the history page.

Comment: @gnometorule: With 10k points you can see other people's review in the recent reviews. So it makes a lot more sense to go there. **Thomas:** Perhaps have the button differentiate between 10k users and non-10k users.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But that's also on the `/history` page. Thomas points out that "recent reviews" open on the `/stats` page, where there is not much to do.

Comment: @This: Yes, I know. But the recent reviews actually shows you what were the recent reviews. Not just the stats.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It sounds like a fine idea to have the button differentiate between user as you say.